# How to use HMAC library in Python as shown in this Java example?

Tags: python, hmac

I need to build an API in Python. However, https://marketplace.api.1worldsync.com/api/ only provide a Java code example.

The URL is required to not be encoded before hash, which is not allowed by hmac function.

I have tried to hash it with URL encoded but failed to match the example provided.

```
msg = '/context/V2/products?app_id=9af172d4&searchType=advancedSearch&query=itemPrimaryId:A00007252147019&access_mdm=computer&TIMESTAMP=2015-10-19T09:58:37Z&geo_loc_access_latd=9.91&geo_loc_access_long=51.51'

base64.b64encode(hmac.new(b'XXXXX', msg=msg.encode(), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()
```

https://marketplace.api.1worldsync.com/api/doc/1WorldSync_Content1_API_HMAC_Guide_v1.1.pdf
Here is the documentation. The expected outcome is on Page 9.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I recently had success with authenticating to 1WorldSync's Content1 API using Python. Please refer to my post regarding this topic on Medium.

1WorldSync's API HMAC Authentication — A Python Sample : https://medium.com/@nitinseelam_72175/1worldsyncs-api-hmac-authentication-a-python-sample-31c446b945ca